# Passing the result of a method to a constructor Java

Tags: java

I want to pass the result of this method.

```
static public int[][] scanCube(Cube c){

    int counter0 = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    counter0 = 0;
    while(counter0 < 4){
        cube[BOTTOM][counter0] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        counter0++;
    }
    return cube;
}
```

To this constructor so that I can call the method above in main.

```
private Cube(int [][] Scancube){
    cube = new int[Scancube.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < Scancube.length; i++){
        cube[i] = Arrays.copyOf(Scancube[i], Scancube[i].length);
    }
}
```

So I can use this in main like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cube c = new Cube();
    Cube.scanCube(c);
    System.out.println(c);
    Cube.solve(c);
}
```

Comment: Can you include code showing us how you plan on using these two methods?

Comment: So what is the Question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  sure I will.

Comment: I wan't to get the result of the method and pass it to the constructor so I can use the method in main. @tkausl

Comment: Hint:  you never use `c` in your `scanCube` method, so you probably *don't* require it.

Comment: The `scanCube` method won't compile as `cube` is undefined unless it is a field. It also does not use `c` (`Cube`), so drop it from the argument list and call `new Cube(scanCube())`.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why don't you just have the static method call the ctor with the arrays and return the new cube? What's the issue? It'd basically be a static factory utility method.

Comment: Looks like the issue is that the chap has not a slightest idea what he is doing...

Comment: I want use `c' from the the object from above then have scanCube take that 'c' and then do Cube.solve(c) . @OlegSklyar

Comment: The problem is that     `cube` is non static 
      'private final int [][] cube;`

Comment: The problem is that     `cube` is non static     `private final int [][] cube;`  and scanCube  uses cube and the user enters in that data in that structure. You cannot use     `cube` in the main method because its not static and since     `scanCube` uses     `cube` it cannot be called in main so what I wanted to do was make another constructor that takes the result of     `scanCube` and uses it in main. @DaveNewton

Comment: Is `cube` part of the Cube class? And if so shouldn't any reference to `cube` in the static method `scanCube` be `c.cube`?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] value= Cube.scanCube(c);
System.out.println(value);
Cube.solve(value);
```

Try like this, as you need to store the value first in the variable of the type you are using then you can pass the variable as a input for your next method.